# program keep automatically closing with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I am trying to write a simple code using selenium at this point I just wait it to open a webpage. Which it does however, it closes it seconds later. My current code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver. maximize_window()
driver.get ("https://www.mmorpg.com/")
```

I Have tried previously using "time.sleep (5)" which works but closes it after 5 seconds which is still not what I'm looking for.

Also, not sure if it matters but I am using "Visual Studio Code" and using "Run > Start Debugging" to run the code.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What does the error/log messages say?

Comment: So that is the thing. I don't see any errors nothing is showing under the "Debug Console" or "Problems" tab

Comment: Selenium error? WebDriver error?

Comment: Can add a line and place a breakpoint on it? (Like string test = 1;). I think the driver is automatically disposed after the test. So on the breakpoint the browser should stay open, resuming ends the test and close the browser

Comment: I think I may have figured out what is causing this. I cant say for certain but when I use "Run > Start Debugging" Visual Studio Code I get the issue. However, when I run it through the CMD terminal in manually by entering "python C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive\Desktop\My_VS_Codes\Project.py" it works fine.